# Undeclared Identifier vector of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier

Error: Line 12 of Cell.h: 'Actor' undeclared identifier.

If I try to forward declare above it, it says that there's a redefinition. What do I do?

Actor.h:

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H
#define ACTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Cell.h"
using namespace std;

class Actor //Simple class as a test dummy. 
{
    public: 
        Actor();
        ~Actor();

};
#endif
```

Cell.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Actor.h"
#ifndef CELL_H
#define CELL_H
using namespace std;

class Cell   // Object to hold Actors. 
{
    private:
    vector <Actor*> test;
public:
    Cell();
    ~Cell();
    vector <Actor*> getTest();
    void setTest(Actor*);
};

#endif
```

Cell.cpp:

```
#include "Cell.h"
#include <vector>

vector<Actor*> Cell::getTest()  //These functions also at one point stated that
{                               // they were incompatible with the prototype, even 
}                               // when they matched perfectly.
void Cell::setTest(Actor*)
{
}
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have recursive `#include`s via your mutual references between `cell.h` and `actor.h`.

In `Cell.h`, delete `#include <Actor.h>`.

In `Cell.h`, add the line `class Actor;` just above the definition of `class Cell`.

In `Cell.cpp`, you *might* need to add `#include "Actor.h"`.

Comment: Made your edits, got the same error as stated in comment above.

Comment: @Twshal that's a different issue. The initial problem was solved by this & my answer. If my comment didn't help, ask a new question. There's tons already on [so], but you'll have to find them yourself. I already showed you the way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Luchian! However it was Robs answer that I'm taking away as having fixed it. You both had similar answers, he just gave more of the right stuff and provided a reason as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `#include "Cell.h"` from `Actor.h` and you're set to go.

In general, prefer forward declarations where you can, and includes where you must. I'd also replace the `#include "Actor.h"` from `Cell.h` with a forward declaration: `class Actor;`.

In the `cpp` files you can include the headers if you need them.

Comment: That halfway worked. Now I'm being slammed with a linker error: >LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Comment: Quick search led me to edit Enable Incremental Linking to No, got me this error.    **Cell.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Student\Desktop\DOCO Simulation_3\DOCO Simulation\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals**

Comment: @Twshal that's a different issue and has to do with the subsystem you use to compile. Google for that exact error message, you're bound to find something useful.

Comment: Still getting weird warning but the build succeeded after compiling main along with it.